# More Information Regarding Upload Restriction in Squid Server

Tags: squid

I've used `request_body_max_size 1024 KB` command in my `squid.conf` file and it is working in restricting my upload of files larger than 1 MB when I try to upload through upload sites.

But I want to know why I am able to upload larger files to sendspace and wetransfer uploading site?

Is there any way to customize uploading in `squid` server 3.1, so that if I want to upload bigger files larger than 1 MB, a screen of username and password will appear and when I enter correct username and password I can upload larger size files?